# Multiplethreading MVVM update value when Current Dispatcher is working

Tags: wpf, multithreading, mvvm, binding

I've problem with update value in window, which is open via `Show()` method not `ShowDialog()` method. I use `MVVM` and use binding like:

```
Value="{Binding Path=MainProgressValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

In my property I use `INotifyPropertyChanged` for notify UI.

It worked fine, but now I open new window

```
 window.DataContext = context;
 if (owner != null)
       window.Owner = owner;
 resultHandler = new ViewModelBaseClass.ResultHandler(context_RequestClosing);
 getDialogResultHandler = new ViewModelBaseClass.GetDialogResultHandler(context_GetDialogResultAction);
 context.RequestClosing += resultHandler;
 context.GetDialogResult += getDialogResultHandler;
 window.Show();
```

There is progress bar. The window is shown and main thread continue with proceed program. But when `DataContext` call `RaisePropertyChanged`, the progress bar doesn't update. Is it possible that the window with progress bar uses another thread than the main thread?

How to update this value?

Comment: I have tried "Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => RefreshDispatherProgressesValues()));" but that doesnt works. Method is calling after main thread finish his work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess based on your description is that you are expecting the UI to refresh while the main application thread is busy doing something. The main application thread is the UI thread so if this is the case you UI thread is blocked.

What you need to do is move the "program" portion that is doing the loading etc. and updating the progress value off into a worker thread (See ThreadPool) and when you want to signal the UI to refresh use the Dispatcher.BeginInvolke() example you found. This will execute your refresh code on the main UI thread.